# How do I make this JavaScript open a page in the iframe I want?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, iframe

So, my website is a little weird. There's a page with an iframe, and when you enter a password it will open another page outside the iframe. For instance, the URL for this site is god-corp.neocities.org.

It gets complicated when I have this whole site inside ANOTHER iframe on another site, like a .com domain. So that domain just has HTML code to show the neocities site if that makes sense. Anyway, when the password is entered and the new page comes up, it just takes you to the neocities site instead of opening it inside of the iframe.

The JS code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function redirect() {
  var input = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
  switch (input) {
    case 'INTRODUCE':
      window.top.location.replace('allwhy.html');
      break;
    case 'VIRTUALIZATION':
      window.top.location.replace('xxxx2.html');
      break;
    default:
      window.top.location.replace(' ');
      break;
  }

}
</script>
```

Help?

Comment: `window.top` refers to the top-most window, outside of any iframes. It's a little unclear if that's what you want or not.

Comment: yeah. if i keep window.top, it opens the site in a whole other tab. if i keep it, it opens in the first iframe, which isn't the one i want it to open in. so i don't know what to put.

Comment: Targeting frames is challenging. Generally I use `window.top.frames[0]`, replacing `0` with the index of the frame I want. I try to keep iframes to one or two though. You may want to start giving the frames ids or classes so you can just do `window.top.document.querySelector('#idOfFrame')`...